# C Macro with variable args - "incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, macros

I'm trying to create a wrapper macro for `vsnprintf`. I'd like it eventually to log the line number if truncation happens, hence I'm making it a macro so I can use the  __LINE __ macro. But the compiler doesn't like what I have so far:

```
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:35:44: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘vsnprintf’ from incompatible pointer type
MYPRINT(buffer,&result,LENGTH,"hello %s","world");
^
foo.c:27:52: note: in definition of macro ‘MYPRINT’
result = vsnprintf(destination,size,format, ## args );  \
^
In file included from foo.c:10:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:390:12: note: expected ‘struct __va_list_tag *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
extern int vsnprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
```

My code is below. I'm not sure how to fix it. Perhaps I need to wrap something in parens?

```
#define LENGTH (512)

#define MYPRINT(destination,result_ptr,size,format,args...) \
  {                                                         \
    int result;                                             \
    result = vsnprintf(destination,size,format, ## args );  \
    *result_ptr = result;                                   \
  }

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int result;
  char buffer[LENGTH];
  MYPRINT(buffer,&result,LENGTH,"hello %s","world");
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `man vsnprintf(): int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list ap);`. That prototype doesn't match your usage. You probably want `snprintf()`.

Comment: Ahh exactly. You could answer so I can accept if that's important to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `vsnprintf()` for this. You should use `snprintf()` and the `__VA_ARGS__` that is to be used with the variadic macros since C99.
`vsnprintf()` is best used with variadic functions, not with variadic macros.

This is a, slightly corrected, version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define LENGTH 512

#define MYPRINT(destination,res,size,format, ...) \
  do {                                                      \
    int m_res;                                             \
    m_res = snprintf(destination,size,format, __VA_ARGS__ );  \
    res = m_res;                                   \
  } while (0)

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int result;
  char buffer[LENGTH];
  MYPRINT(buffer,result,LENGTH,"hello %s","world");
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that since `MYPRINT` is a macro (and not a function) you don't need to pass the pointer to the variable `result`. You are actually passing the *name* of the variable itself. As you are doing now you, you will have a conflict between the `result` declared in the main and the `result` declared in the macro body block.

I've added the idiom `do {} while(0)` to ensure the macro is treated as a single statement by the compiler.

Hope it helps.